# Open remote content in the Bootstrap modal window

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

All I need is a simple example in how to open a remote content into a Twitter Bootstrap modal window.

I'm using Bootstrap v2.0.4 and I just can't get it to work. I can open regular modal windows, but I can't make it open a remote file inside it.

Comment: v2.0.4 doesn't support remote content in modal out of the box. Update your bootstrap to latest if you want to use Bootstraps built in support.

Answer (score 23):

First, remote data must fulfill the same origin policy. If you're not satisfying that, everything after this is going to fail (if you are trying to load external URL's, see [Twitter Bootstrap external URL's are not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12153741/570918)).

There are two ways to accomplish loading remote content into a modal with the Bootstrap data-api.  Namely to either specify the remote url to load in the `<a>` element which triggers the modal or to specify the url in the modal's markup.

In the former, one uses the **href** property:

```
<a data-target="#myModal" href="/remote/url" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>
```

In the latter, one uses the **data-remote** property:

```
<div class="modal fade hide" id="myModal" data-remote="/remote/url">...</div>
```

The advantage of specifying it in the `<a>` element is that one could have a different remote url for each `<a>`, yet still only use a single modal.  Using the **data-remote** property might be more advantageous in situations where you have multiple means of launching a modal with the same content.  Then, no matter what launches it (even a JS call), it would consistently provide the same remote content, without having to duplicate that information across all the methods of invocation.

Here is a demo using the latter method:

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/cp67J/)

The content in the body of the modal is the remote html.

Comment: I've a file named remote.html and that's the file that I'm trying to load into it. I just tried your code with data-remote="remote.html" and it's not working...can you help me? :)

Comment: Was the `data-remote="remote.html"` on the `<a>` or the element with the `.modal`?  It should be the latter.  Also, perhaps try using a root relative url, like "/remote.html".  Are you seeing any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Yes, I'm using your JSFiddle code, it looks like this: `<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-remote="/remote.html">` no errors on browser...it just doesnt load the content and show it as "one fine body"

Comment: Unless you can set up a test page I can view, I'm at a loss as to how to move forward.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/cp67J/ seems to work on google-chrome but not on firefox 16.0.1

Comment: @Pietro What wasn't working with it? I just realized that I forgot to put the initial class `hide` on the modal, so it was causing it to block mouse events on the button when the viewport was too small. That is now updated and everything works in FF for me.

Comment: Now works for me too. Without the hide works only on chrome. Without hide but with 2.1.1 bootstrap works with firefox too :-)

Comment: If you are using the div option, and php, using the standard include option in php works IE <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade">
     <?php include "inc_modal.php"; ?>
  </div>

Comment: For Rails: = link_to 'target', nil, :data => {:toggle => 'modal', :target => '#target', :remote => target_path }... I had to _omit the href_. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I dropped a working example here on JSFiddle that illustrates how to use a link to open a bootstrap modal containing a remote URL (of the same origin). It's an almost verbatim copy-paste from [twitter's bootstrap docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) with some minor modifications to make it work for remote URLS.

It just comes down to pointing the **href** attribute to the URL you want to open and the **data-target** attribute at the DIV that acts as the modal window.

[JSFIddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/matt_hwy1/hRq82/1/)

Same code here:

```
<!-- Button to trigger modal -->
<a href="/matt_hwy1/uEQEP/4/show/" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal Test Header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>​
```

Comment: here's an update of  this fiddle that demonstrates that the first clicked-on link becomes the source of the data from then on. if you click the first link, the second link loses, and vice versa. http://jsfiddle.net/rbpasker/hRq82/113/

Comment: If we try to use same modal for dynamically loading different content based on a href, it doesn't destroy the modal content and keeps the copy of last modal reference - e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/AYcne/

Comment: The example posted doesn't seem to open in modal.