# Nothings showing in my modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, remoteobject

My question is similar too, if not the exact same as [This one about modals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153503/twitter-bootstrap-modal-external-urls-are-not-working). The problem seems to be, that my .txt file wont load into the modal body:

```
<p><a data-toggle="modal" href="http://adambalan.com/aisis/aisis_version_notes.txt" data-target="#modal" class="updateNotes">READ MORE ABOUT IT!</a></p>

    <div class="modal hide fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
  </div>
</div>  

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('a.updateNotes').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.modal-body').html(url);
    });​    
});
</script>
```

any ideas?

Comment: Did you even read the answer to the question you linked?

Comment: yes I did, how ever I am not rendering a site so an iframe isn't needed, even with it in, still nothing renders.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not trying to get cross-domain content, I think you code is correct. Since you are using `data-api` syntax, actually you don't need to write any JS to bring the content from the link. Bootstrap modal javascript would do it for you. Are you including the 'bootstrap.js' file ?