# Show new page as Modal with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on an Python Flask application, were I'm writing python program, HTML5 and making use of Bootstrap too.I'm struck with Javascript, because I'm new to it.

I've an table in my page, where "id" be assigned to an value. I can able to get the id value using

```
<script>
    $("table tr").click(function(){
    alert (this.id);
});
    </script>
```

I wanted to send the "id" value to another page, and open the resulting page as Modal. Can you guide or share sample code for the same...?

Comment: Depends on what your modal window would be! Is it a complete html page which can have an url like 'your/url/id'? Or is it something like a fresh template and the id u generated is to get specific data??

Comment: "I wanted to send the "id" value to another page". You cannot send anything to an other page. I'm guessing that want to give the "id" to the server, and respond with a new page based on this variable, and make this this new page appear in a modal. Right ?

Comment: @TCHdvlp Yes, I need to send the "id" value to server and get the response, and show the data in modal

Answer (score 0):

If you have already downloaded bootstrap plugin then my answer would be very easier  for you.
Earlier i have written same thing that you required in PHP [(have a look)](http://docs.safesquid.com/). Whatever be the language its about JQUERY and HTML5.

You just trigger the following line using JQUERY then it will open the second page content in modal format.

```
<a data-toggle="modal" class="trigger" data-target="#yourid" href="second_page.php" ></a>
```

Trigger the above line as

```
$("table tr").click(function(){
    $('.trigger').trigger("click");
});
```

Your second page content should be like

```
<div id="yourid" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Give a title name</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

                   <!-- Place your second page content here -->

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152101/open-remote-content-in-the-bootstrap-modal-window) also. Correct me if am wrong

Comment: In "Modal-body" area can I load page of dynamic URL? Your answer looks promising...

Comment: Yes you can.. as TCHdvlp said. Or else if possible you may use iframe too.

Comment: @Ramkee will the iframe load after the event is triggered?

Comment: Yes i hope! when modal-body loads at that time iframe will be called.